# Objects are not valid as a React child - use array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So I realize that objects can't be rendered, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to fix this error after trying to add a loading spinner when fetching data. Once I added the ternary operator, the data no longer passed to my child component and gave me the error code above. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [marsData, setMarsData] = useState([]);

  const getMarsData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);

      const res = await fetch('/api/nasa/mars');

      if (res.ok) {
        const jsosData = await res.json();
        setMarsData(jsosData.photos.slice(1, 6));
      } else {
        throw new Error(res.statusText);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => console.log(marsData), [marsData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMarsData();
  }, [getMarsData]);

 return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        marsData
      ) : (
        <Col s={4}>
          <Preloader active color="blue" flashing={false} size="big" />
        </Col>
      )}
      <MarsRoverPhotos data={marsData} />

      <MarsWeather />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is my MarsRoverPhotos component

```
const MarsRoverPhotos = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Slider
        fullscreen={false}
        options={{
          duration: 500,
          height: 400,
          indicators: true,
          interval: 6000,
        }}
      >
        {data.map((d) => (
          <Slide image={<img key={d.id} alt="" src={d.img_src} />}>
            <Caption
              placement="right"
              style={{height: '30px', paddingTop: '175px'}}
            >
              <h3>{d.camera.name}</h3>
              <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3">
                {d.camera.full_name}
              </h5>
            </Caption>
          </Slide>
        ))}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: you can't just render an array like this `{isLoading ? marsData :`, maybe you can try `isLoading ? marsData.map(each => <div>{each}</div>) : `

Answer (score 0):

The error it's telling exactly what to do:

Can't see what you are doing with this component:

`<MarsRoverPhotos data={marsData} />`

But you are passing the response from `jsosData.photos.slice(1, 6)` which its an object not an array, so React is complaining that you are trying to render object, but React don't know what to do with it.

Probably inside of `<MarsRoverPhotos data={marsData} />` you have something like:

```
return (<div>{marsData}</div>) // <-- that its rendering an object
```

The solution:

You should check what are your receiving on `jsosData.photos.slice(1, 6)` most likely you are a receiving something like:

```
{
  "someId1": { value: "imgSrc" },
  "someId2": { value: "imgSrc"}
}
```

So what you need to do its iterate over the object the easy and standard way its:

```
function MarsRoverPhotos(props) {
   const {data} = props;

    return Object.keys(data).map(key => <div>{data[key].value}</div>)
}
```

And you should be able to render your component. cheers!

Comment: Yeah so I've added my MarsRoverComponent code and I did map through the data in that component beforehand which worked fine until I wanted to implement the loader, which is where I think the problem lies, but I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: const jsosData = await res.json();
setMarsData(jsosData.photos.slice(1, 6));
**setLoading(false); ** // <-- are you missing this?

Comment: while I did setLoading(false) in my finally statement, I did manage to fix the overall issue by using conditional rendering. Not sure if that's the most efficient way, but it looks good. Thanks

Comment: { isLoading ? <Load /> : <YourComponent />  } yeah that its very valid

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way, but I did seem to solve it via a more basic approach to conditional rendering.

```
if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Col s={4}>
          <Preloader active color="blue" flashing={false} size="big" />
        </Col>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <MarsRoverPhotos data={marsData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```